# How to drive ${{ e^{\lambda h }- \lambda h + \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 } } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 } } } = 1+ O(h^2 \lambda^2 )$ ??

Tags: analysis

Why $\displaystyle {{ e^{\lambda h }- \lambda h + \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 } } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda } } } = 1+ O(h^2 \lambda^2)$ ?

I have only one hint : Using Taylor's Thoerem!
But i don't get it.

$\displaystyle {{ 1 + \lambda h + h^2 \lambda^2 / 2 + O (h^3 \lambda^3 ) - \lambda h + \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 } } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda } } }$
$\displaystyle = {{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 / 2 + O (h^3 \lambda^3 ) + \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 } } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda } } }$
$\displaystyle = 1+  {{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 / 2 - \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 }  } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda } } }+ O (h^2 \lambda^2 ) $

I think $\displaystyle {{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 / 2 - \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda^2 }  } \over {2 \sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda } } }$ is problem. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: Expand  $\sqrt{ 1 + h^2 \lambda ^2} $ too.

Comment: What the... Thanks!